# Call Controler not with full name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I am new with ASP.NET MVC.we create a controller like this 'AdminController' but call it only with the name of Admin. How ASP.NET MVC handle this that we don't need to call controller with full name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller name you specify in the URL is not the same as the class name, just as the action name is not the same as the actual method that on the controller. There is internal mapping between the controller/action and the class/method that MVC does when determining what code needs to be executed.

The generic mapping rule is:

- for controllers, take the controller name (`Admin`) and add the suffix `Controller` to it and search for a class with this name (`AdminController`).
- for actions, take the name of the action (`Details`) and search for a method on the controller with the same name (`ActionResult Details() {}`).

However, currently MVC supports explicit mapping of an action to a method with different name through the [`ActionName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute.aspx) attribute. Thus, you could have an action called `Edit` that is mapped to a method `ActionResult EditUser() {}` for example.

It is possible that future versions of MVC could add also a similar `ControllerName` attribute that allows explicit mapping of a particular controller name to particular class. (In fact, I hope they do, to help solve the problem with providing different implementations of the same controller name in different areas)

Answer (score 1):

This is handled by the Asp.Net MVC framework using Routes. We define routes in Global.aspx.cs.  The route defines which controller to be called and what action to be performed for a given url e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = ""}
                );
```

Also Asp.net MVC prefers Convention over configuration. So as a convention 'Home' means HomeController.